# How does Ray and intersectRayTriangle work?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So basically I want to check wheter a laser beam from a cannon hit terrain. Either I don't understand Ray concept or something is wrong.
Let's take this line of code

```
Intersector.intersectRayTriangle(intersectorRay, new Vector3(0.5f,1,0), new Vector3(0.5f,-1,0), new Vector3(1,0,0), hitPoint);
```

intersectorRay has origin 0,0,0 and direction 1,0,0 so I assume it is pointing "straight right" from point 0,0.
So given the coordinates of the triangle's vertices it should intersect with it right? The code returns false.

Now this line on the other hand returns true:

```
Intersector.intersectRayTriangle(intersectorRay, new Vector3(0.5f,1,0), new Vector3(0.5f,-1,0), new Vector3(-1,0,0), hitPoint);
```

Testing on other examples proven that it returns true only if origin of Ray is inside triangle (well it's obvious that it hits something in this case...).

What do I do wrong?
I am using latest nightly version of libgdx from 6 Sept.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go out on a limb here and say that the reason it returns false in your first example is because the ray does not pass through the face of the triangle, due to it being on the same xy plane that the ray is shooting across.

If, instead, your triangle were on a zy plane (or any other plane that was not exactly the plane the ray was shooting across) I suspect you would get the result you expect.

Comment: So it seems that I am misusing Ray class then. I understand that it is created for camera or rendering reasons.
Now, how should I check what I want to check in 2D environment? I guess I will write something on my own cause the time is running and I have to finish my project. Probably I change all obstacles' polygons into segments and check segments intersections.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say you are necessarily misusing Ray, it's more that the Intersector methods assume that if you are using a Ray, you are in 3D space (and specifically looking for an intersection with the face). Perhaps this is a wrong assumption and it should treat a Ray shooting across the same place as a Triangle is on as a valid intersection.